# to embarass = to feel anxious/worried

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

The [online Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/embarrass) gives two definitions of "to embarass":

- to cause someone to feel anxious, ashamed, or uncomfortable
- to cause someone to feel nervous, worried, or uncomfortable

AFAIK "to embarass" means "to cause someone to feel ashamed or uncomfortable". *As a result* , the person may get anxious, nervous or worried, but that is not the root meaning of the word and thus "to embarass" is not a synonym of "to feel anxious, nervous or worried". For instance, the second sentence in each pair sounds very odd to me:

- I have a test/date tomorrow and it is making me feel anxious (= I have a test/date tomorrow and it is embarassing me)
- Global warming affects us all and it worries me (= Global warming affects us all and it embarasses me)
- My children are mischievous and make me nervous every day (= My children are mischievous and embarass me every day)

Are these definitions of "to embarass" in the Cambridge dictionary somewhat confusing or have I misunderstood the scope of the verb?

Answer (score 1):

The challenge here is that "embarrassment" is such a specific emotion, that it's difficult to define with other terms.  I'm certain many (if not all) languages have a word to define embarassment so there is no real confusion in translation.  We know what emotion it describes.

The Cambridge definition does the best it can, but even something like "abash" can only really be swapped with "embarrass".  FumbleFingers suggests "ashamed" but I think there is nevertheless a subtle difference between feeling *shame* and feeling *embarassment*.   Shame implies guilt or at least a sense of wrongdoing. Embarassment is simply the feeling you get when you are part of something contrary to your own expected social norms, but not any serious violation of convention.

Again, I suspect many languages have similar words to distinguish between the two, but a clear definition is tricky. We can but describe what embarrassment feels like or what causes it, as a way of defining what it is.

Which is to say: In my opinion the Cambridge definition is inaccurate, but it's hard to think of a more accurate one. This is one case perhaps where the translation dictionary is the best reference.

Comment: You might be embarassed if you were coughing at work and your dentures flew out of your mouth, or you were publicly told that your fly was undone, or you broke wind while being introduced to the Queen, but it is a different emotion from shame.

Comment: Not sure why the emotion is not shame in your example with the dentures. Only because the action is unintentional? In the case of meeting the Queen, IMHO the emotion is self-consciousness or uncomfortableness, which are synonyms of embarassment AFAIK. I still don't think that "to embarass" is a synonym of "to cause someone to feel anxious, nervous or worried" and IMHO it is a bad definition of the Cambridge dictionary.

Comment: Shame is felt over something bad or blameworthy. It is not shameful to wear dentures.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista in my opinion the Cambridge definition is inaccurate, but it's hard to think of a more accurate definition

Comment: @Andrew for instance, "to cause someone to feel ashamed, uncomfortable, or ill at ease" seems much better to me. I am not a native English speaker, so please correct me if I have missed some nuance.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista better perhaps but still misleading. It's like defining "yellow" or "up".  Some words are axiomatic.